# Hostname in Peer to Peer Wireless Networking using Socket between two Mobile devices

Tags: c, networking

My goal is set up a wireless peer to peer networking using socket. Server and Client model. The code for Server is such.

Server.c

```
int sockfd, newsockfd, portno, clilen;
     char buffer[256];
     struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
     int n;
     if (argc < 2) {
         fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no port provided\n");
         exit(1);
     }
     sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
     if (sockfd < 0) 
        error("ERROR opening socket");
     bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
     portno = atoi(argv[1]);
     serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
     serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
     serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
     if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,
              sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
              error("ERROR on binding");
     listen(sockfd,5);
     clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
     newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
     if (newsockfd < 0) 
          error("ERROR on accept");
     bzero(buffer,256);
     n = read(newsockfd,buffer,255);
     if (n < 0) error("ERROR reading from socket");
     printf("Here is the message: %s\n",buffer);
     n = write(newsockfd,"I got your message",18);
     if (n < 0) error("ERROR writing to socket");
```

Client.c

```
 int sockfd, portno, n;

    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    struct hostent *server;

    char buffer[256];
    if (argc < 3) {
       fprintf(stderr,"usage %s hostname port\n", argv[0]);
       exit(0);
    }
    portno = atoi(argv[2]);
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0) 
        error("ERROR opening socket");
    server = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
    if (server == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no such host\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    bcopy((char *)server->h_addr, 
         (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,
         server->h_length);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
    if (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
        error("ERROR connecting");
    printf("Please enter the message: ");
    bzero(buffer,256);
    fgets(buffer,255,stdin);
    n = write(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer));
    if (n < 0) 
         error("ERROR writing to socket");
    bzero(buffer,256);
    n = read(sockfd,buffer,255);
    if (n < 0) 
         error("ERROR reading from socket");
    printf("%s\n",buffer);
    return 0;
```

My questions are

1)What's the hostname I should set in the server.c in one of the Mobile Phone? Or what should the hostname the client (another one of the Mobile Phone) expect to see.

2)what should I use for port number for TCP communication between two Mobile devices. ANything above 2000?  Let say I have one iPhone and one Android and I am trying to setup peer to peer wireless networking between the two.

Answer (score 0):

For your second question. YOu will have to use a port number that is known to both devices, otherwise the client would not know the port number on which to invoke connect() and thus, establish the connection with the server. Now, first 1024 are reserved but so are some of the ports beyond 1024! You can find hte list here: http://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml . The largest numebr I see is 49151, so I would start with a random value between 49151 and 64K. Lastly, since TCP layer is standard, picking a common port number should not matter if you use an iPhone with Android or any other TCP-aware device.

Your first question is tricky. The more basic question is how do you discover the peer? May be, the peers can broadcast messages once in while to help others discover them -- broadcast messages are UDP messages and once can know the sender and the port number from received UDP messages. Next, the TCP client can use that and then connect to the peer. In fact, you can also have the host send a broadcast message (as long as you fix the port number for your app) and let the clients reply. Needless to say, you dont want to send these discovery floods too often.

Answer (score 0):

Answering your first question the hostname can be anything which is registered with DNS. Specifying an IP address will also do the trick but make sure its a Public IP.

The Port number can be any number that the server machine is not bound to. It is recommended to have above 2000 but not necessary.

One thing to keep in mind is in socket programming we are dealing with sockets which are either UDP or TCP (L4) (unless you are talking about RAW sockets). So this means we are not worried about L2 (whether it is wired or wireless). This implies that your code will work the same for both wireless, wired, and hybrid.